# Is the canvas empty?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, dom-events

I'm trying to make a scratch card using canvas with JS. my question is:
can I know if the user have "erased" all the canvas?

I have two images one on top the other, and I managed to make the user "erase" the on-top canvas image. I want to fire up a function when the canvas is empty\completly erased.

Thanks

```
var offsetT;
var offsetL;

    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.id = "canvas";

    var canvasWidth = 290;
    var canvasheight = 269;

    canvas.width = canvasWidth;
    canvas.height = canvasheight;

    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var scratcher = document.getElementById("scratcher");


    var radius = 20;  //Brush Radius


    context.drawImage(scratcher,0,0);

    // set image as pattern for fillStyle
    context.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-out';
    context.fillStyle = context.createPattern(scratcher, "repeat");

    // for demo only, reveals image while mousing over canvas
    canvas.onmousemove = function (e) {
        var r = this.getBoundingClientRect(),
            x = e.clientX - r.left,
            y = e.clientY - r.top;

        context.beginPath();
        context.moveTo(x + radius, y);
        context.arc(x, y, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
        context.fill();
    };
    document.body.appendChild(canvas);

    document.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e){

        var touchobj = e.changedTouches[0]; // reference first touch point (ie: first finger)
        var x = touchobj.clientX;
        var y = touchobj.clientY;

        offsetT = canvas.offsetTop;
        offsetL = canvas.offsetLeft;

        context.beginPath();
        context.moveTo(x-offsetL + radius, y-offsetT);
        context.arc(x-offsetL,y-offsetT, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
        context.fill();

        var cursor = document.getElementById('cursor');
        cursor.style.display = 'block';
        cursor.style.left = x+ "px";
        cursor.style.top = y+ "px";
        e.preventDefault();
    }, false);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way is to check the imageData of the canvas :

```
var data = ctx.getImageData(0,0,ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height).data;
var isEmpty = !Array.prototype.some.call(data, function(p){return p>0;});
```

```js
var ctx = c.getContext('2d');

var isEmpty = function(ctx){
  var data = ctx.getImageData(0,0,ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height).data;
  return !Array.prototype.some.call(data, function(p){return p>0;});
  }
//first check before drawing
log.innerHTML += isEmpty(ctx)+' ';

//no more empty
ctx.fillRect(0,0,10,10);

// recheck
log.innerHTML += isEmpty(ctx);

/*
we could also have used a for loop : 

//in Function
for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
  if(data[i]>0){
    return false;
    }
  return true;
  }
*/
```

```html
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
<p id="log"></p>
```

Comment: PS : actually it may not be the only way. You could also create an `ImageData.data` like Array yourself, and check as transparent all the pixels around the event's coordinates for the radius of your eraser, but this may be a real harsh with antialiasing calculations etc. Also I wonder how much you would win compared to the still too slow `getImageData`, but I won't write it until I really need it so this "easiest solution" I did provided here will remain my only solution ;-)

Comment: **You have an interesting idea:** An array that represents pixel alpha values. *A possible improvement*: Divide the whole canvas into many (maybe 10) arrays which cumulatively have all alpha values. Then as 1+ arrays become "fully transparent", you can speed up testing by totally ignoring any fully transparent arrays. Interesting! :-)