# 60fps: How to use requestAnimationFrame the right way?

Tags: javascript, performance, animation, scroll

On my website, a related content box should be animated into the viewport when it gets visible.

I’m trying to make my animation as efficient as possible through CSS and JavaScript, so that it doesn’t affects scroll performance negatively.

While the CSS part was simple (using transform, will-change, contain), I’m struggling a bit with when to use `window.requestAnimationFrame`.

Should I use it only when the class is added to the element or also when the function `isScrolledIntoView` is called or even inside `isScrolledIntoView`, when the elements position is measured?

```
var percentVisible = 0.25;
window.addEventListener('scroll', function(){
relatedContent(related, percentVisible);
}
)

function relatedContent(r, pV){
    window.requestAnimationFrame(function() {
        if(isScrolledIntoView(r, pV)){
            window.requestAnimationFrame(function(){
                r.classList.add("visible");
             }, r)
        }
    }, r)
}

function isScrolledIntoView(el, percentV) {
var elemTop, elemBottom, elemHeight, overhang, isVisible;
/*window.requestAnimationFrame(
function(){*/
elemTop = el.getBoundingClientRect().top;
elemBottom = el.getBoundingClientRect().bottom;
elemHeight = el.getBoundingClientRect().height;
/*}
);*/
overhang = elemHeight * (1 - percentV);

isVisible = (elemTop >= -overhang) && (elemBottom <= window.innerHeight + overhang);
return isVisible;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

No don't use it like that...

- requestAnimationFrame (rAF) is a timing function that does synchronize with the screen refresh rate (generally 60fps).
- Scroll event may fire more often than 60 events per second.
- Each call to rAF will stack all the functions passed as its parameter in some kind of a big function called just before the next screen refresh.

Combine all of this and what you get is multiple calls to the same function in a stack, just before the next screen refresh.

Instead, what you seem to want is to prevent your scroll event to fire when not useful. This is called a throttle function, and you're a bit far from it.

Here is a simple throttle implementation using rAF :

```
var throttle = function(callback) {
  var active = false; // a simple flag
  var evt; // to keep track of the last event
  var handler = function(){ // fired only when screen has refreshed
    active = false; // release our flag 
    callback(evt);
    }
  return function handleEvent(e) { // the actual event handler
    evt = e; // save our event at each call
    if (!active) { // only if we weren't already doing it
      active = true; // raise the flag
      requestAnimationFrame(handler); // wait for next screen refresh
    };
  }
}
```

That you could use like this :

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', throttle(yourScrollCallback));
```

Comment: Curious if this is the right way to add the event listener, because how would you remove it correctly?

Comment: @DrewBaker this indeed doesn't expect the event handler will be removed.l, just like OP's code. If you wish to be able to remove it in the future you can either hold a reference of the throttled function and pass it both to addEventListener, then later to removeEventListener, or you can pass an AbortSignal in the addEventListener's options and abort its controller when you don't need the handler anymore.

Comment: However this answer is actually outdated, the scroll event now does already fire at the screen refresh rate, so there is no need to throttle it with rAF anymore. I'd have to update it when I get time.

Answer (score 2):

`requestAnimationFrame` [returns a non-zero `long`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame#Return_value) that can be used to cancel your request, so instead of writing your own throttle implementation, you can use the following simpler approach to prevent multiple handlers stacking up:

```
let currentRequest;
document.addEventListener('scroll', function () {
  cancelAnimationFrame(currentRequest);
  currentRequest = requestAnimationFrame(handleScroll);
});
```