# debounce/throttle is ruining my fixed-header effect

Tags: javascript, scroll, lodash, throttling, debouncing

I have written some javaScript so that my menu starts off as position: static but will become position: fixed and stay at the top of the screen whenever the user scrolls upwards but will disappear again whenever scrolling downwards. Because the menu has some content above it, once the user has scrolled to the very top, the menu becomes position: static again.

This code works ok but I am having a problem when adding debounce. I've read I need either throttling or debounce for performance. I have tried using both the Lodash _.debounce and _.throttle functions separately. I don't mind having some delay on the menu showing itself on scroll-up, but with a debounce the header has a delay when returning to position: static once the user has scrolled back to the top of the page. I have tried using the {'leading': true} option for the debounce and throttle function but it hasn't done much good.

If I set my wait/delay time too low, surely there is no point in even using debounce or throttle anymore? I do not want to sacrifice the performance of the site but have been asked to implement this effect.

```
 var header = document.getElementById("fixed-header");
 var offset = header.offsetTop;
 var $header = $(header);
 var headerHeight = parseInt($header.css("height"));
 var total = headerHeight + offset;

 var lastScrollTop = 0;
 window.addEventListener("scroll", _.debounce(scrollHeader, 200, {
     'leading': true
 }));

 function scrollHeader() {
     var st = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
     if (st > lastScrollTop) {
         // downscroll code
         if (pageYOffset >= total) {
             document.body.classList.add("fixed");
             document.body.classList.add("is-hidden");
             document.body.style.paddingTop = header.offsetHeight + "px";
             header.style.transition = ".5s";
         } else {
             document.body.classList.remove("fixed");
             document.body.classList.remove("is-hidden");
             document.body.style.paddingTop = 0;
         }
     } else {
         // upscroll code
         if (pageYOffset >= offset) {

             document.body.classList.add("fixed");
             document.body.classList.remove("is-hidden");
             document.body.style.paddingTop = header.offsetHeight + "px";
         } else {
             header.style.transition = "initial";
             document.body.classList.remove("fixed");
             document.body.style.paddingTop = 0;
         }
     }
     lastScrollTop = st;
 }
```

Comment: lodash's `debounce` and `throttle` use setTimeout as timing function. Maybe you should try with [a `requestAnimationFrame` based throttle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38942741/60fps-how-to-use-requestanimationframe-the-right-way/38943316#38943316), at the cost of losing the delay parameter, but with the advantage to fire before the next repaint.