# HTML Canvas get total fill in percent

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I doing a canvas to restore the original image when cursor moving around, in different percentage to show in different message to tell user. How to calculate the total percentage that already filled?

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var context =  canvas.getContext('2d');

context.beginPath();
context.fillStyle = 'black';
context.fillRect(0, 0, 400, 300);

canvas.onmousedown = function() {
    canvas.onmousemove = function() {

        var x = event.clientX;
        var y = event.clientY;
 
        context.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-out";
        context.beginPath();
        context.arc(x-0, y, 30, 0, Math.PI*2);

        context.fill();
    }
}

canvas.onmouseup = function() {
    canvas.onmousemove = function() {
        //
    }
}
```

```html
<img src="http://blog.honeyfeed.fm/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/onepiece-wallpaper-20160724205402-560x380.jpg" style="width: 400px; height: 300px; position: absolute; z-index: -1;" />
<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="300"></canvas>
```

Comment: This seems mostly a math question, and might be better asked of mathematicians, of which I am not one; percentage equals total area of canvas minus ( number of times function triggers multiplied by the area of the brush ) minus total area of brush overlaps.

Comment: @FredGandt I know it is math, but math in code, I not sure Mathematicians can understand coding

Comment: mhmm. Hopefully a mathy coder swings by.

Comment: @Kaiido not duplicate , that not the answer I looking for , thanks

Comment: @Kaiido I tried your code from that question , it work well for detect the canvas is empty or not, but how can I calculate how much is filled ?

Comment: @ImHappy I updated the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/phgos32w/4/) on the linked Q/A, file (from asker) gone 404. If it isn't what you are asking for, then please clarify. **Oh my bad!**, I pasted the wrong link to the Q/A !!! **The correct one is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36035664/canvas-transparency-mask-effect-percentage-masked/36036916#36036916).** Unfortunately I won't be able to CV again... So if someone with CV rights could do it...

Comment: @Kaiido Thumb Up for you. The answer is what I actually looking for ! Thanks you !

Comment: @Kaiido Check my algo again *"... minus total area of brush overlaps."*. I did miss out a pair of parentheses though.

Comment: @FredGandt, yep missed that bit of your comment. Apologies. (It would still be hard to get this *total area of brush overlaps*  through Maths though ; if even possible)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Canvas transparency mask effect percentage masked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36035664/canvas-transparency-mask-effect-percentage-masked)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to "brute force" this calculation, you could use `getImageData` and check the total number of pixels that is transparent.

The main code:

```
// This returns an array with 4 bytes (0-255) per pixel
// data[0] -> R value of first pixel
// data[1], [2], and [3] -> G, B, and A values
// etc.
const data = context
  .getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
  .data;

// The total number of pixels is the length of the 
// data array divided by 4, or width * height
const nrOfPixels = data.length / 4; // rgba pixels
let transparent = 0;

// Your code removes the alpha, so we check each
// 4th item in the array (notice the += 4)
// If it's transparent (A === 0), we count it
for (let i = 3; i < data.length; i += 4) {
  transparent += data[i] ? 0 : 1;
}

// The percentage is the number of transparent pixels
// divided by the total number of pixels
const percentage = transparent / nrOfPixels * 100;
```

<strike>This is by no means an optimized way of doing this. That's why, for now, I included it in the `mouseup` event listener and put a `console.time` around it.</strike>

**EDIT:** because I felt guilty that I answered a duplicate question with almost the exact same solution as was apparently linked in the comments, I optimized for performance. Now I feel this answer actually adds an additional solution.

The optimization:

- We divide our canvas in to a grid of squares size `s`
- One array holds the transparent pixel count per box
- Another array holds the top left coordinate for boxes that need recalculation
- **On every mouse move**, we calculate the four corners of a box surrounding our cleared circle
- For each corner's x,y location, we check in which of the grid boxes it lies
- We mark this grid box as "dirty", which means it has to be checked for changes.
- **On every mouse move**, we use `requestAnimationFrame` to request a new update calculation
- In the update, we **do no longer retrieve all image data**. Instead, we only request the image data for our *dirty* grid boxes.
- We calculate the transparency for every grid box, add them up and divide by the number of total pixels.

The size of the grid and the size of the brush determine the performance gain of this approach. With the settings in the example below, I was able to get a performance gain of around 400% (4.x ms per calculation to <1ms)

Note that the grid size must be larger than your brush size.

```js
const GRID_SIZE = 50;
const DRAW_SIZE = 30;

var ExposeImage = function(canvas, display) {
  const width = canvas.width;
  const height = canvas.height;
  const cols = width / GRID_SIZE;
  const rows = height / GRID_SIZE;

  this.gridBlocks = Array(rows * cols);
  this.dirtyBlocks = Array(rows * cols);

  const gridBlockIndex = (c, r) => r * cols + c;
  const rcFromBlockIndex = i => [
    Math.floor(i / cols),
    i % cols
  ];

  this.context = canvas.getContext("2d");
  this.display = display;

  this.init();

  var logDirtyGridBoxes = function(e) {
    var x = e.clientX;
    var y = e.clientY;
    var r = DRAW_SIZE;

    var top = Math.max(y - r, 0);
    var bottom = Math.min(y + r, height - 1);
    var left = Math.max(x - r, 0);
    var right = Math.min(x + r, width - 1);

    var corners = [
      [top, left],
      [top, right],
      [bottom, right],
      [bottom, left]
    ];

    corners.forEach(c => {
      const row = Math.floor(c[0] / GRID_SIZE);
      const col = Math.floor(c[1] / GRID_SIZE);
      const i = gridBlockIndex(col, row);
      this.dirtyBlocks[i] =
        /* top left of the grid block */
        [col * GRID_SIZE, row * GRID_SIZE];
    });

  }.bind(this);

  var update = function() {
    console.time("update");
    
    // Store the transparent pixel count for all our dirty
    // grid boxes
    this.dirtyBlocks.forEach((coords, i) => {
      const data = this.context.getImageData(
        coords[0], coords[1], GRID_SIZE, GRID_SIZE).data;

      this.gridBlocks[i] = transparentPixelCount(data)
    })

    // Clear dirty array
    this.dirtyBlocks = Array(rows * cols);

    // Calculate total average
    const total = this.gridBlocks.reduce((sum, b) => sum + b, 0);
    const avg = Math.round(
      total / (width * height) * 100);

    console.timeEnd("update");
    display.innerText = avg + "%";
  }.bind(this);

  // Event listeners
  var onMove = function(e) {
    this.clear(e.clientX, e.clientY, DRAW_SIZE);

    logDirtyGridBoxes(e);
    requestAnimationFrame(update);
  }.bind(this);

  canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", function(e) {
    canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", onMove);
    onMove(e);
  }.bind(this));

  canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", function() {
    canvas.removeEventListener("mousemove", onMove);
  }.bind(this));
};

ExposeImage.prototype.init = function(context) {
  this.context.beginPath();
  this.context.fillStyle = 'black';
  this.context.fillRect(0, 0, 400, 300);
  this.context.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-out";
};

ExposeImage.prototype.clear = function(x, y, r) {
  this.context.beginPath();
  this.context.arc(x - 0, y, r, 0, Math.PI * 2);
  this.context.fill();
};

// App:
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var display = document.querySelector(".js-display");
var ei = new ExposeImage(canvas, display);

function transparentPixelCount(data) {
  let transparent = 0;
  for (let i = 3; i < data.length; i += 4) {
    transparent += data[i] ? 0 : 1;
  }
  return transparent;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://blog.honeyfeed.fm/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/onepiece-wallpaper-20160724205402-560x380.jpg" style="width: 400px; height: 300px; position: absolute; z-index: -1;" />
<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="300"></canvas>
<div class="js-display">0%</div>
```

Comment: Which is the same as this [linked Q/A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36035664/canvas-transparency-mask-effect-percentage-masked/36036916#36036916) (not marked as dupe because of an error of mine, but [recognized as one by OP in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43928602/html-canvas-get-total-fill-in-percent#comment-74891513)) except that this other one does work... Btw, If you can use of your CloseVote power to propose it, it would be great.

Comment: Ah.. Didn't see any links or answers in the comments. I'll mark as a duplicate but will leave my answer here until it's closed.

Comment: percentage: `Array.prototype.filter.call((data, index) => index % 4 === 3 && data === 0).length / (data.length / 4) * 100` just saying.. but ye. it would probably be efficient since getImageData alone will eat alot of time.

Comment: @Kaiido I edited my answer with a performance optimization. I felt I had to add something to the discussion because our answers turned out so similar!

Comment: Good idea, but somehow your get grid might be wrong : https://i.stack.imgur.com/aD7Gk.png

Comment: Good catch! I had made several mistakes. Should be fixed now, although the code is a bit messy. I kind of feel like nobody's ever going to read through it, but if somebody does I'll be happy to clean it up. Let me know.

Comment: Nice answer, I know it's an old thread but it did exactly what I needed. Is it maybe possible to fire a function when the percentage reaches for example 10%?